# Rails 3 - Production environment - smtp email issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, smtp, actionmailer

I am using smtp settings for sending mails in rails 3. It works fine when `sendmail` and `postfix` services are running. But when I stopped those two services then mails stop sending and giving me connection error.

**Error log** -

```
ERROR -- : (Errno::ECONNREFUSED): Connection refused - Connection refused
org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyTCPSocket.java:126:in `initialize'
org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1178:in `open'
```

Comment: can you provide SMTP config

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

If you do not pass any config in your application then it will try to connect localhost on port 25. In your case, this has stopped your SMTP services, that's why you are getting an error.

So, please add these details below in your config .. in `application.rb` or depending on your need you can put on `development.rb` or `production.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address        =>  smtp.mailgun.org, # smtp service provider name
    :port           => 587, # port number of smtp server 
    :authentication => 'plain', #plain ////
    :user_name      => '', #user name
    :password       =>'', #password
    :domain         =>  '',#domain name 
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```